# An equivalent condition for a rectangular band.

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

This is Exercise 1.9.4 of Howie's *"Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory"*.

> **Definition:** A semigroup $S$ is a rectangular band if $aba=a$ for all $a,b$ in $S$.
>
> **Lemma:** Let $S$ be a rectangular band. Then every element of $S$ is an idempotent.

*Proof:* Let $a$ be an element of a rectangular band $S$. Then $a^3=a$ implies $a^4=a^2$. But $a^4=a(a^2)a=a$. Hence $a^2=a$.$\square$

### The Question:

> Show that a semigroup $S$ is $(A)$ a rectangular band if and only if $(B)$ for all $a,b$ in $S$, $ab=ba$ implies $a=b$.

### My Attempt:

For $(A)\implies (B)$: Let $S$ be a rectangular band. Let $a, b\in S$ such that $ab=ba$. Then
$$\begin{align}
a&=aba \\
&= (ba) a \\
&=ba \\
&=b(ba) \\
&=bab \\
&=b.
\end{align}$$

> But I don't know how to show $(B)\implies(A)$.

Please help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements $a$ and $a^2$ commute, so by $(B)$ we have $a^2 = a$ (every element is an idempotent).

We infer that elements $a$ and $aba$ commute: 
$$ abaa = aba = aaba, $$
hence $(B)$ implies $aba = a$.